# Excel Question: Filter Column 1, Find last in Column 2, Return value Column 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how solve an excel issue I have. I have Three Columns of data, and I need to find the "current" value. Example:

[image: Example]

Basically I want to filter on the first column, do a "find last" on the second column, and return the value that sits to the right of the second column.

I've tried INDEX-Matching, and Vlookups, but I can't seem to make it work. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your provided sample data in a setup like this:

[image]

There are two possible solutions depending on what you're actually looking for.

To always return the BOTTOM date (which might not necessarily be the most recent date), the formula in cell G2 and copied down is:

- `=LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$2:$A$10=E2)*($B$2:$B$10=F2)),$C$2:$C$10)`

To always return the MAX date (or most recent date, but not necessarily the bottom date), the formula in cell H2 and copied down is:

- `=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$10=E2)*($B$2:$B$10=F2)*$C$2:$C$10,))`

In both cases, adjust the ranges to suit your actual data.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!! Works great!